# Git can't invoke gpg-agent to sign commits

Tags: encryption, git, gnupg, digital-signature

I have Git 2.8.1 running in Ubuntu 15.10, and I've set it up to GPG sign all of my commits using my keybase key. It used to work well.

At one point, I'm not sure what caused it, I started getting errors from gpg:

```
> $ git commit --all

You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "keybase.io/madara <madara@keybase.io>"
4096-bit RSA key, ID ........., created 2015-06-16

gpg: problem with the agent - disabling agent use
# At which point, it asks me for the passphrase, I input the correct one
# And still get the fatal errors below
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

When I go to `~/.gnupg/pgp.conf` and disable the `use-agent` line, it works from terminal (but then I need to input the very long passphrase for each commit I want to sign).

My GPG_AGENT_INFO environment variable is

```
echo $GPG_AGENT_INFO
/tmp/gpg-27dtzi/S.gpg-agent:1557:1
```

I don't know how to debug/approach it, so if I'm missing any important info, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 3):

As a temporary workaround this helped me:

```
killall gpg-agent
```

Found here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2156806&p=12774930#post12774930

Comment: Is this a known bug? Is there no real solution until the ubuntu core team fixes it?

Comment: Perhaps it's already fixed in gnupg 2.1 series (which _requires_ the agent)?